# How to change Button listener back and forth based on some action in Android

Tags: android

I am creating chatting app and chatSendButton is used to send message to reciever

```
chatSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            try {
                                sendMessage();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

. Now when user tries to reply to a message i change the button listener like this.

```
 chatSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            try {
                                sendReplyMessage(reply);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Now the problem is that when sendReplyMessage(reply) is completed i want the button listener to go back to previous listener. Now i have tried changing the button listener at the last line of sendReplyMessage(reply) function but when i click on the button the app restarts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have some state to know what you want the button to do, something like

```
button.setOnClickListener(() -> {
   if(isReply) sendReply()
   else sendMessage()
});
```

Just remember to save the state in somewhere so it does not get reset after lifecycle events. ViewModel or `onSavedInstanceState`